# Remove blank dates from each rows using SQL

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have the below dataset from where I am trying to remove blank termination date, the logic here is this, if there are 2 termination dates (1 blank and 2nd has actual termination date), then remove the blank date for that particular entry, on the below dataset you can see every 4 records are duplicates untill the termination date is blank for 4 records and 4/29/2020 for other 4 records, I want to remove the blank terminationd dates, and this can happen for each of the employees, how can I achive this one, I tried to right the below statment but no luck:

```
    WITH cte AS 
  ( SELECT 
*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY  
  [ID]

  ORDER BY 
      [TerminationDate]
   ) row_num FROM adp.adppaydata ) --DELETE 


   select * FROM cte WHERE row_num > 1 and [TerminationDate]  <> ''
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried 'and termination date is None'?

Comment: I dont have NULL in my dataset as you can see, then how can I try that one?

Comment: What about =="" then

Comment: can you be specific?

Comment: Personally I would try `DELETE FROM adp.appdata WHERE TerminationDate=""`

Comment: That will delete all the record I want to fit the above logic so that only rows gets deleted where record matches from there specific rows where termination date is not blank, and then delete the rows where date is blank with respect to rows where date is not blank.